# struts2 prepare and validation

Tags: validation, parameters, struts2, interceptor, prepare

Im trying to ensure that when an action is called, the expected parameters are given (like to show a user profile I want to be sure that parameters contains the user id : viewUser.action?userId=1 should work well but viewUser.action should redirect to an error page)

So I created a validation xml that specifies that the userId field can not be null. Everything works fine.

But now, on prepare() I do some pre-work using the userId.
The fact is that prepare interceptor is called before validation interceptor so if userId is null then I have a nice nullPointerException and the validation is not called because the error happened before.
I know I can switch the interceptor order but I don't want to.

So my question is :
Im I supposed to use parameters inside prepare() methods ? Is there any other way to handle that ?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "paramsPrepareParamsStack" interceptor stack.

Comment: So I will have params => prepare => params => validation. But I will still have a problem using idUser in prepare if it's null.

Comment: @Estragon You can't check to see if it's null? Or your business logic that uses it doesn't do any sanity checks?

Comment: Of course I check all inputs but I don't believe prepare is the place to check that and validation system should be better that manually checking in prepare / business functions ... Also I dont really know how to react if parameters are null in prepare

Comment: @Estragon So, you don't want to change the order of the intereptors, and you don't want to check manually. Sounds like you're out of luck.

Comment: Well his other choice is to change how he thinks about the problem, so paramsPrepareParamsStack is not needed, that may be worth knowing but is the longest road.

Comment: @Quaternion It's needed if you don't want to get the parameter from the request manually.

Comment: @DaveNewton well I meant changing his thinking so service methods didn't need initialisation with parameters within his action... so change his thinking about the problem to make everything more elegant. Digging the parameters out of the request is most certainly another option although one that defeats Struts2 and any sense of ascetics.

Comment: @Quaternion Oh. I don't have a problem using params in a prepare; just depends on the needs. I haven't done it a lot, but occasionally it's quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

Your can change default order of the interceptors in your struts-default.xml file, so checkbox and params interceptors will start before prepare interceptor.

```
<interceptor-stack name="basicStack">
  <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

But i don't like this idea. I thing the better way is to change your action logic and remove all parts of code from prepare function if they use some parameters. Why your do it in "prepare"? Your want to use the results during validation?

Comment: The `prepareParamsPrepareStack` already exists for this purpose; why do it yourself? That aside, OP already stated that switching interceptor order wasn't desirable for whatever reason.

Comment: Ah, your mean paramsPrepareParamsStack? Yes, this is better solution.

Comment: Whoops, yep--got those backwards, I must have forgotten in the intervening 30 minutes ;)

Comment: @Estragon "Also I dont really know how to react if parameters are null in prepare". 1. Use validation function in your action this time, not validation.xml. 2. Remove all logic whith idUser from prepare to validation (If your want to execute it before the "execute" so mach). 3 If your find a problem with idUser duering validation simle use addFieldError("idUser", "idUser error message")

Answer (score 0):

What follows is an explanation as to how to avoid this issue and make over all development easier however the most immediate solution is most certainly Daves. I would definitely implement that first and be done with the issue and use the following in the future.

In my experience prepare() is used to acquire services which will let the action do it's job which is best served by Dependency Injection (Spring).

Generally the action class is responsible for the following:

- Getting objects needed to perform the action (service objects).
- Getting parameters needed to perform the action(used by the service objects to get what we need).
- Verifying the parameters make sense (validation method/annotations, could externalise to xml).
- Performing the action (using the service objects previously mentioned).
- Getting the objects needed for the view...

This you know and you also know that prepare is about getting the objects needed to perform the action (ideally service objects although some people do things like opening up DB connections). The actual doing should be restricted to the execute method.

Going with the ideal route, which is using service objects injected with your DI provider of choice (Spring/Guice), we find our selves having little to no reason to need the prepare method at all. Our actions get smaller, easier to understand and easier to test as a result.